# Get Discount Type in Cart

Tags: cart, ce-1.9.0.1, discount

I need to be able to get the discount type applied in the cart.

I can get the discount amount like so:

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
$totals =  $cart->getTotals(); 
$discount = $totals["discount"]->getValue();
```

How can i check what type of discount it is - whether it is a percentage or fixed amount off?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `applied_rule_ids` in `sales_flat_quote` and `sales_flat_quote_item`

You could try something like

```
 //if the item has not had a rule applied to it skip it
 if($item->getAppliedRuleIds() == '')continue;

    /*
    * I cant remember in the database they might be comma separated or space if multiple rules were applied
    * the getAppliedRuleIds() function is the one you want
    */
    foreach(explode(",",$item->getAppliedRuleIds()) as $ruleID){        

        //Load the rule object
        $rule = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule')->load($ruleID);

        // Throw out some information like the rule name what product it was applied to

        echo "<p>".$item->getSku()." had rule ".$rule->getName()."(".$item->getAppliedRuleIds().") applied </p>";
 }
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649695/magento-get-price-rules-from-order